# Patent explanation help

Tags: patent-infringement

Can somebody please help me with understanding this [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8368701B2/en). I am not sure does this patent forbid CPU-GPU synchronization at all. I am particularly interested in terms of parallel programming with CUDA toolkit. For example, the CUDA toolkit provides a function for the synchronization (*CudaDeviceSynchronize*) of GPU and CPU. Does the function infringe the patent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patent is highly technical. You need to understand the claims to determine what is covered. Remember, to infringe a claim you need to implement each and every step in the claim.

What I will suggest is that you are very, very unlikely to be sued for infringement by utilizing NVIDIA's CUDA toolkit. If the CUDA toolkit infringed a patent, no doubt either NVIDIA would already have been sued for infringement or else they would have negotiated a license. However, I am not a lawyer so this is not legal advice.